# Folland Chapter 6 Problem 23b

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space. A set $E \in \mathcal{M}$ is called "locally null" if $\mu(E\cap F) = 0$ for every $F \in \mathcal{M}$ such that $\mu(F) < \infty$. For $f: X \to \mathbb{C}$ measurable, define $\|f\|_* = \inf\{a : \{x : |f(x)| > a\} \text{ is locally null}\}$.

Problem 23b asks to show $\|\cdot\|_*$ is a norm on the set of $f$ such that $\|f\|_* < \infty$ (modded out by $f=g$ iff $f=g$ a.e.). In particular, we must have $\|f\|_* \ge 0$. I claim this does not always hold. For example, consider $X = \mathbb{R}, \mathcal{M} = \mathcal{P}(X)$, and $\mu(A) = 0$ if $A$ is at most countable, and $\mu(A) = \infty$ otherwise. Then $X$ itself is locally null so any $a < 0$ satisfies $\{x : |f(x)| > a\}$ is locally null.

The author gives no restriction on the measure space. Is the problem flawed?

Comment: I believe the $\inf$ should be taken over $a> 0$ (see e.g. Chapter 3 of Cohn's book on Measure Theory). Also, as usual, in order for this to be a norm, two functions should be considered equal if they are equal almost everywhere.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to include that but he says $f = g$ if $\{x : f(x) \not = g(x)\}$ is locally null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's flawed, but only superficially. Changing $\inf\{a : \{x : |f(x)| > a\} \text{ is locally null}\}$ to $\inf\{a > 0 : \{x : |f(x)| > a\} \text{ is locally null}\}$ makes the problem correct.